# Cant connect to mysql server (hosted by strato) get error 10060

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlconnection, navicat

Hi I am trying to connect to my MySQL DB which is hosted by strato. On their site I can create a DB and I did. Now I am trying to connect to the database via NaviCat but I keep getting error 10060.

A screenshot of the strato website: [screenshot strato webportal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBl0Q.png)

A screenshot of my trying to connect to the database in NaviCat: [screenshot NaviCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcmDr.png)

And last but not least a screenshot of their website with an tutorial on how to connect to the DB: [link to page](https://www.strato.com/faq/en_us/article/567/This-is-how-you-can-use-our-MySQL-database.html)

Maybe you're wondering why I don't contect the host, it takes ages for them to reply...

What am I doing wrong why cant I connect how can I fix it?

**EDIT/UPDATE**

I now setup a SSH tunnel but when I am trying to connect it still gives me this error`lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet' system error 0`

I am able to connect via PuTTy like shown [in this link](https://www.strato.com/faq/en_us/article/567/This-is-how-you-can-use-our-MySQL-database.html). And a found the port, hostname etc as you can see [image: on this screenshot]

But once I fill that into NaviCat, like this [image: general settings]

and this

[image: this]

but still no luck :S now gettings this error: [image: error]

If anyone can help me i would rlly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have permission to connect remotely to this database? Some hosts block remote connections for security purposes.

Comment: Can you telnet to the service to verify you can get to it over the network?  Sometimes companies cut off access from the outside.  Also, look here, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94102/remote-mysql-connection-fails-10060-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-domain#94185

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that Strato is blocking outside access to your database. Which is 100% good. Allowing internet access to a database is generally a bad idea.

You can connect to the database by SSH'ing to the server and then using `mysql` CLI. [Instructions are provided in the link you shared](https://www.strato.com/faq/en_us/article/567/This-is-how-you-can-use-our-MySQL-database.html) in the *SSH-access to the MySQL database* section.

Using SSH you can also port tunnel to allow your remote connection with your client. This is a slightly more advanced technique where you link up a port on your local computer (localhost) to a port on the remote machine to which you are ssh'ing.

In PuTTy put in the server name like their instructions suggest:
[image]

Then go to SSH>>Tunnel in the left-hand menu. Fill out your Source Port (the port your local computer will be listening on) and your Destination (The server:port on the REMOTE computer that you are forwarding traffic to through the tunnel):

[image]

I'm using local port 66306, you may use whatever port you want as long as it isn't be used on your computer. Click "Add" and then Open the connection and put in your username/password when prompted. Refer to that Strato help doc if you get stuck.

NOW... in your mysql client (Navicat) you are going to connect your database. Because you have a tunnel open forwarding traffic from YOUR computer's 63306 port (or whatever port you chose) to the remote computers 3306 port you will specify in Navicat:

```
Connection Name: Whatever
Hostname/IpAddress: localhost
Port: 63306
Username: strato db username
Password: strato db password
```

Now it should connect. Strato sees your traffic as if it's coming from their server because of the tunnel and it will allow you through.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer I'll look into it tomorrow

Comment: Okie doke. Good luck! SSH tunneling is a good technique to learn. It can get you around all sorts of firewall issues as long as SSH port is open and you have a remote computer to catch the tunnel.

Comment: I can connect now via PuTTy but I still cant connect to it using NaviCat or MySQL Workbench. I edited the post

Comment: To use the navicat's built in SSH tunneling (instead of doing the tunnel manually in PuTTY) then in the General tab use `localhost` as the hostname and the port of the mysql server (3306, most likely). Your SSH tunnel tab looks correct.

Comment: Looks like Strato blocking any tunnel: `channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`